# Teradata CONCAT a String and a modified Date format

Tags: datetime, concatenation, teradata, datetime-format, teradata-sql-assistant

I am trying to CONCAT a String and a Modified date format. I have two requirements

First one, **I need the output to be in the output window be like**

1. Cost Month: Month YYYY format( where month should be previous month only). for ex-

**Cost Month: March 2022**

2. Report Date: MM/DD/YYYY(Todays current date)

**Report Date: 04/20/2022**

For the second requirement, I am trying something like

```
SELECT CONCAT ('Report Date' , 'SELECT CURRENT_DATE(FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy') (vARCHAR(12))') as Report_Date
```

But ofcourse it isn't working

Comment: You're concatenating the literal string beginning with `SELECT`, not executing that as a query. You also didn't escape the nested quotes

Comment: That's not how you format a date in MySQL. You use the `DATE_FORMAT()` function. Are you sure MySQL is the database you're using?

Comment: Sorry, I am using Teradata Sql assistant, but, it uses the same similar syntax, CURRENT_DATE works in mssql too!

Comment: mssql is not mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close:

```
CONCAT ('Report Date: ' , (CURRENT_DATE (FORMAT 'mm/dd/yyyy')) ) as Report_Date
```

Similar for cost month (using `||` instead of CONCAT):

```
'Cost Month: ' || (add_months(current_date, -1) (FORMAT 'mmmmByyyy'))
```

Comment: Perfect! :D thank you so much pal